# prop-types doesn't work in React Native App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

PropTypes doesn't work for me in React Native. I think the code is fine but this way RN doesn't warn me about Prop-types violations and defaults props doesn't even works, I don't know why.

My npm packages: 
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4"

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { Modal } from "@ant-design/react-native";

import config from "./config";
import styles from "./styles";

const ModalAlert = ({
  title,
  content,
  okeyCallback,
  cancelCallBack
}) => {
  const renderTitle = title => <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>;

  const renderContent = content => (
    <Text style={styles.content}>{content}</Text>
  );

  const renderBtn = text => <Text style={styles.btn}>{text}</Text>;

  cancelCallBack
    ? Modal.alert(renderTitle(title), renderContent(content), [
        {
          text: renderBtn(config.texts.confirmText),
          onPress: () =>
            okeyCallback === null ? console.log("Ok pressed") : okeyCallback()
        },
        {
          text: renderBtn(config.texts.cancelText),
          onPress: () =>
            cancelCallBack === null
              ? console.log("Cancel pressed")
              : cancelCallBack()
        }
      ])
    : Modal.alert(renderTitle(title), renderContent(content), [
        {
          text: renderBtn(config.texts.confirmText),

          onPress: () =>
            okeyCallback === null ? console.log("Ok pressed") : okeyCallback()
        }
      ]);
};

ModalAlert.PropTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  content: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  okeyCallback: PropTypes.func,
  cancelCallBack: PropTypes.func
};

ModalAlert.defaultProps = {
  title: "deafult"
};

export { ModalAlert };
```

Answer (score 2):

should be:

```
ModalAlert.propTypes = {}
```

Comment: I imported as PropTypes. I wrote it as propTypes anyway but still doesn't work btw. I mean, this way: ModalAlert.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired, {...} }

Comment: The errors will not be print in your terminal but in your browser console.